# Switch branches with default branch in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch, rename

In a repo I'm working, we created a named branch at some time to try a different approach in a certain issue. We continued to work in the default branch as well.

Now that the named branch has matured so to speak, we would like to make that branch, the default one, and give a different name for the (old) default branch.

Is something like that possible?

I've found this question, [Mercurial: Can I rename a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378684/mercurial-can-i-rename-a-branch) and I can rename the default branch successfully, but afterwards when I try to rename the named branch to default, it fails with an error

```
abort: a branch of the same name already exists
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You need to close all the branches and then give them the required name

PS: seems like you just needed to add `-f` flag to the branch command

Sample scenario

```
hg init
echo "123" > file
hg addremove
hg commit -m "init default"

hg branch new
echo "new" >> file
hg commit -m "init new"

hg up default
echo "default" >> file
hg commit -m "default 2nd"
hg commit --close-branch -m "close default"


hg up new
hg commit --close-branch -m "close new"

hg branches # none

hg log # see where to update if haven't saved id/hash somewhere

hg up 3 # this changset was the "close default" one
hg branch new -f
hg commit -m "new new"

hg up 4 # the changeset we closed "new" at
hg branch default -f
hg commit -m "new default"
```

The result:

[image]

```
>hg log -G
o  changeset:   6:af87a53292cf
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      4:700a73ac7cad
|  user:        Ivan Kurnosov
|  date:        Tue Jun 05 17:22:27 2012 +1200
|  summary:     new default
|
| @  changeset:   5:4ee990605ba1
| |  branch:      new
| |  parent:      3:6ebccfc3e630
| |  user:        "Ivan Kurnosov
| |  date:        Tue Jun 05 17:18:01 2012 +1200
| |  summary:     new new
| |
o |  changeset:   4:700a73ac7cad
| |  branch:      new
| |  parent:      1:4a149d3fe86e
| |  user:        "Ivan Kurnosov
| |  date:        Tue Jun 05 17:15:18 2012 +1200
| |  summary:     close new
| |
| o  changeset:   3:6ebccfc3e630
| |  user:        "Ivan Kurnosov
| |  date:        Tue Jun 05 17:14:49 2012 +1200
| |  summary:     close default
| |
| o  changeset:   2:92669a82423b
| |  parent:      0:05657f61324b
| |  user:        "Ivan Kurnosov
| |  date:        Tue Jun 05 17:13:07 2012 +1200
| |  summary:     default 2nd
| |
o |  changeset:   1:4a149d3fe86e
|/   branch:      new
|    user:        "Ivan Kurnosov
|    date:        Tue Jun 05 17:12:30 2012 +1200
|    summary:     init new
|
o  changeset:   0:05657f61324b
   user:        "Ivan Kurnosov
   date:        Tue Jun 05 17:11:51 2012 +1200
   summary:     init default
```

Comment: Would it be easy to give a simple example? :)

Comment: Great. -f did the job. Afterwards I had also to do `hg push --new-branch -f`. Might add that as well to you example to be complete. :)

Comment: PS. What GUI are you using in your screenshot above?

Comment: @George Kastrinis: it's tortoisehg