# TeamCity issue with anonymous branch in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, teamcity

An anonymous branch was created by backing out of a change. This branch was then pushed and is now public. The branch name is just a load of white spaces which I am having trouble referencing.

I have 3 branches, default, rc and stable, and I use TortoiseHg to interface with mercurial.

Every time I try to update to the anonymous branch I get the invalid arguments error. When I try to merge I get an abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect, error. I can update to the 1011 commit which the anonymous branch is on, but I cant see what I can do from there.

[Commit history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVCg5.png)

The image above shows my commit history. In it you can see the anonymous branch, my failed attempt to rebase it (new_for_1008 branch) and my attempt to close both the rebase branch and the anonymous branch. If I attempt to push I get the following error...

hint: merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads.

The reason this anonymous branch is causing issue is that my VCS connections in team city are getting confused. When I try to run anything link to this repository I get the following error.

Failed for the root '"SITENAME Default" {instance id=301, parent internal id=33, parent id=SITENAME_SITENAMEDefault, description: "mercurial: http://hg/REPONAME"}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty branch name

Could anyone let me know where I'm going wrong and what else I could try to remove/rename the anonymous branch. Or if there is something else I could do to fix the VCS connection.

Thanks,

Comment: Could try to rename the branch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378684/mercurial-can-i-rename-a-branch